# Get just the first item from a multiple valued field using field_view_field()

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I'm using [`field_view_field()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_view_field/7) to get the render array for a image field that has multiple values. I then use `drupal_render()` on that resulting array to print out the markup.

I only want the first image to be returned in the markup for that field. Is there a way to either manipulate the rendered array to remove the other fields or a setting when call `field_view_field()` to say only return first row?

Comment: Can you print_r() the return value of your field_view_field() call and add that to your post? That will make it easier to help you.

Comment: Can't really post all the code from that field_view_field() call as it's huge and includes the entire node array too. But you can replicate it by creating an image field with multiple instances enabled and then call the field_view_field() function from a custom module.

Comment: Have you considered using [field_view_value](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_view_value/7)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using [field_view_value](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_view_value/7)?  It is the recommended way to retrieve a single value from a multi-value field.